# Pass Text-box Value to Another Page

Tags: php, html, echo

How can i pass the text-box value to another page? Here is code: the 254 value should appear on the second page.

First Page:

```
Total Price:<input name= "totalprices" type="text" disabled="disabled"  class="form-control autocomplete-location" id = "totalprices"  value="254">
```

2nd Page:

```
echo $_POST['totalprices'];
```

Comment: Is this input wrapped in a form which is posting to the 2nd page?

Comment: wrap it on a form.. and specify the location of the form when you submit..

Comment: Whats the intension behind making field disabled if you want to post this value to 2nd page?

Comment: Yes.    <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentform" method="link" action="process.php"> Process.php is my second page.

Comment: Disabled fields wont get send in a form.

Comment: change disable to readonly `<input name= "totalprices" type="text" readonly="readonly"  class="form-control autocomplete-location" id = "totalprices"  value="254">`
`

Comment: Oh, let me try,Thanks!

Comment: 1. Disabled controls do not receive focus. 2.  Disabled controls are skipped in tabbing navigation. You can use readonly. By doing this you can send data to next page

Comment: There is no `method="link"`. It should be `method="POST"`.

Comment: Thank you so much, wait i'll try :) i'll update you.

Answer (score 2):

To send disabled items to the POST array you can use readonly attribute.

```
<input name= "totalprices" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control autocomplete-location" id = "totalprices"  value="254">
```